As a Tunisian student who got a Visa Schengen (France), what are the requirements i need to fulfill in order to enter the mexican territory?
Precisely, I want to know if I have to enter the French territory (therefore using my visa in France) before going to Mexico?

Not posting as an answer as IDK if there are further rules on this. However Mexican Immigration says only “Visa válida y vigente de Canadá, de los Estados Unidos de América, Japón, el Reino Unido de la Gran Bretaña e Irlanda del Norte o cualquiera de los países que integran el Espacio Schengen”. That is, the visa must be valid and current, but there is no mention of used.

Is your Schengen visa a multiple entry visa?

@Traveller The wording in the Mexican immigration site is imprecise. It'd be easy to assert that a single-entry visa which has already been used for a single Schengen entry is no longer "current," even if the visa's use-before date is still in the future. If the site used the word "used," the meaning would be clearer.

@DavidRecallsMonica I agree, which is why I didn’t post as an answer. Personally, I wouldn’t try this unless I had a used and current/valid multiple entry visa.

Thank you everyone for your answers! Unfortunately i don’t have a multiple entry visa but single entry
